# Buscar y retornar el valor en común entre 2 array con javascript

Tags: javascript, array

De la siguiente manera sólo muestra el 5, pero no el 7 ni el 9. No se que tengo mal:

```js
let array1 = [2, 5, 40, 7, 9]
let array2 = [1, 5, 60, 7, 9]

function numeroEnComun(array1, array2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if (array1[i] === array2[j]) {
          return array1[i]
        }
      }
    }
}
console.log(numeroEnComun(array1,array2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Tu código termina con el return cuando encuentra el primer número en común. Quizás deberías intentar crear un arreglo donde guardes los resultados y añadirlos en lugar De hacer el return. 

Como resultado del método, deberías hacer return del arreglo donde guardaste los resultados.

Comment: ¿No puedes usar los métodos funcionales del objeto Array?

Comment: Con este código te vale `const numerosEnComun = array1.filter(x => array2.some(y => y===x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como te han comentado el principal problema es la sentencia `return` que tienes dentro de tu función. Toda sentencia `return` dentro de una función hace que la misma finalice. En tu código esto significa que no se seguirá iterando nada más apenas se consiga la primera coincidencia que satisfaga la condición establecida en la sentencia `if`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Suponiendo que deseas "devolver" los valores comunes en ambos Array, entonces lo suyo es entregar un Array con dichos valores comunes o un Array vacío si no existen valores comunes entre los 2 Array.

Esto implica que debemos permitir que se recorran totalmente los 2 Array, y en vez de usar una sentencia `return` usaremos el método [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) para añadir el elemento coincidente (si lo hubiera) al nuevo Array. Al final devolveremos el Array resultante.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const array1 = [2, 5, 40, 7, 9]
const array2 = [1, 5, 60, 7, 9]
const array3 = [0, 1, 3, 4, -5];

function numeroEnComun(array1, array2) {
    const coincidentes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if (array1[i] === array2[j]) {
          coincidentes.push(array1[i]);
          break;  // salgo del bucle, no necesito seguir buscando
        }
      }
    }
    return coincidentes;
}

console.log(numeroEnComun(array1,array2));
console.log(numeroEnComun(array1,array3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Mejora**

Para Array mucho más grandes, tu función es muy costosa en términos de [complejidad temporal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complejidad_temporal). Es por ello que muchas veces es mejor apoyarse en métodos funcionales propios del lenguaje ([javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) es un lenguaje funcional).

En particular podemos usar 2 métodos:

- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): que devuelve un nuevo Array con los elementos que superan un determinado filtro.
- [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes): devuelve un valor verdader o falso si el Array contiene o no un determinado elemento.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const array1 = [2, 5, 40, 7, 9]
const array2 = [1, 5, 60, 7, 9]
const array3 = [0, 1, 3, 4, -5];

function numeroEnComun(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(el => arr2.includes(el));
}

console.log(numeroEnComun(array1, array2));
console.log(numeroEnComun(array1, array3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 1):

te faltaría guardar los valores de la intersección antes de retornar

```js
let array1 = [2, 5, 40, 7, 9]
let array2 = [1, 5, 60, 7, 9]

function numeroEnComun(array1, array2) {
  const interseccion = []
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
      if (array1[i] === array2[j]) {
        interseccion.push(array1[i])
      }
    }
  }
  return interseccion;
}
console.log(numeroEnComun(array1, array2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Alternativa usando sets

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#iterando_set

```js
let array1 = [2, 5, 40, 7, 9]
let array2 = [1, 5, 60, 7, 9]

function numeroEnComun(array1, array2) {
  const mySet1 = new Set(array1)
  const mySet2 = new Set(array2)
  const intersection = new Set([...mySet1].filter(x => mySet2.has(x)))

  return [...intersection]
}
console.log(numeroEnComun(array1, array2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```